# C ++ error I keep getting this error variable-sized object `OldWord' may not be initialized

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype> 
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"Palindrome.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        Stack S1;
        string word;

        cout << "Do you know what a Palindrome is?\n";
        cout << "It is a word that is the same spelling backwards and forward\n";

        cout << "Enter in a word";
        cin  >> word;

        char OldWord[word.length] = word;
                cout << OldWord[2];
        return 0;
}
```

If I put 20 in place of word.length, I get "invalid initializer" for error

Comment: This isn't even valid; your array sizes must be known at compile-time. And as far as I'm aware, you can't initialise an array with a `std::string`. I'm kind of surprised it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Well, arrays are neither copyable nor assignable; you have to copy them in a loop, element by element (or use a function that does that for you).  In addition, the length of a local array variable must be a compile-time constant; you can't set it at runtime.

Also, `std::string` is not an array; why do you think that this assignment would work?

`std::string` does allow array-like access, though, so you can use `word[2]`, assuming there are at least three characters in the string.  In general, raw arrays should be avoided in C++; there are much better options, like `std::string`, `std::vector`, and `std::array` (or `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array`).

Answer (score 0):

Leave it with 20 instead of word.length and use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) to initialize.

Comment: -1 for what is at best an incomplete solution:  one should never suggest `strcpy` without pointing out that the caller is responsible for bounds checking.

Answer (score -1):

The value needs to be copied into OldWord.

Try changing:

```
char OldWord[word.length] = word;
```

to

```
char OldWord[20]; // you mentioned 20...
strcpy(OldWord, word.c_str());
```

Comment: This looks like a bad idea: what happens when I type in _supercalifragilisticexpialidocious_? There is no reason to resort to using a raw array here and using `strcpy` without any length checking is A Bad Idea.

Comment: @James - I'm a string fan and probably would have used one here. The reason I didn't suggest it here is because suggesting a string would not answer why the specific error was occurring and I believe thats what the question is about.

Comment: No, sometimes the problem is that the **question** is wrong. :-) If someone tries to do something really strange, like copying a std::string to an array, it is better to suggest a simpler solution that works better.

Comment: @Bo - Sometimes users downgrade an answer because it doesn't answer the specific question or solution in the answer has deviated to far from the question/example code and sometimes an answer is downgraded because it doesn't change the question/example code enough.  It's a delicate balance that I'm still trying to master ;)  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks you all your answers helped out alot.